# Why is the deconstructor called on an empty pointer

Tags: c++

I am having a hard time understanding why the deconstractor of null pointer is called when I call `delete`.Since the content of the pointer is null and I didn't even reserved any space for the object with `malloc` or `new` what deconstructor is it calling?

```
class Sak{
    public:
        Sak(){cout << "defalt constructor" << endl;}
        ~Sak(){
            cout << "deconstructor" << endl;   
        }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Sak* s;
    delete s;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output:

```
deconstructor
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Please, for the love of all things holy, don't use the abomination that is [system("PAUSE")](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html). Its behavior is unpredictable -- how would you know what 'pause' does on my machine, maybe it pauses the coolant pump on my nuclear reacor. And it marks you as an incompetent programmer who doesn't understand how to code in C++.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: … I agree, but isn't that *unpredictable behavior* still a bit better than *undefined behavior* in the previous line? (None should be there…)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas In practice, the damage undefined behavior does is almost always limited to the scope of what the program accesses. It could format your hard drive or fry your hardware, but it almost never does. On the other hand, invocation of external programs is much more likely to do actual damage. (Though one can argue that if you call a program `PAUSE`, you deserve what you get.)

Comment: `delete s;` this is UB for a pointer that wasn't allocated with `new()`. Correctly initialized `nullptr` values are transparent for `delete`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I wouldn't consider corruption of any or all files opened by the program to be surprising.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas , My professor is using system("PAUSE") in all of his examples ,I understand the problems with that but for now since I am not making the next farcry here its an easy way to achieve what I need.

Comment: @SteveL Scary. That's a sign that your professor doesn't understand the C++ language or consider portability to be important.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: There is actually no portable way in the standard library to do the same thing that Windows Command Prompt pause command does. Hopefully one day the standard library will get some proper keyboard functionality.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Agreed! Same for the `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` :P ...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Isn't requiring/waiting for an `<ENTER>` enough, does it really need to be _any key_ for such purpose?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The standard library doesn't have that functionality either. And being able to press any key is a better interface.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley C'mon just a `std::cin >> dummy;` would do fine.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Not if there's leftover data from a previous input operation.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Fair point! Would a `std::cin.clear()` call before help?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: No. All that does is clear error state of the stream. It has nothing to do with the input data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Sak* s` is an uninitialised variable - it could contain any garbage value at all.  Reading from an uninitialised value is *undefined behaviour*, so your program is broken as soon as you attempt that.

Still, in practice - and for the sake of explaining the observed behaviour - most implementations would read whatever happens to be at `s`'s stack address and pass that to `delete`.  If that value happens to be 0, then `delete` will do nothing - per the Standard.  Otherwise - we have a situation similar to say:

```
Sak* s = (Sak*)1;
delete s;
```

What `delete` normally does for a non-0 pointer is invoke the destructor - `~Sak` - *then* attempt to deallocate the memory (which will also be undefined behaviour and might or might not crash the program).  Still, it's unsurprising that you're seeing the destructor output first.

It's also noteworthy that the destructor invocation would typically be passed the object address (e.g. `1` for the code above) as the `this` pointer: your destructor doesn't use `this` in any way, not even implicitly (e.g. to invoke a destructor for a data member with non-trivial destructor, such as a `std::string`), so your destructor's likely to return successfully.

Comment: Note that the probable behavior changes if the destructor is virtual.

Answer (score 5):

You have `Sak* s;` which does not create an empty reference or a null reference but rather an uninitialized pointer. If you want a NULL pointer, use `Sak* s = NULL;`.

Your code is just broken, using the value of `s` (by passing it to `delete`) without initializing it (by setting it to some known value). It's behavior will be strange and unpredictable.

Comment: yea but I thought that the space for the object is being reserved upon s=new Sak(); and not at the moment I create the reference?

Comment: Formally, it is *undefined behavior* to call `delete` on a pointer which is neither assigned to NULL nor gotten from `new`.

Comment: @SteveL That's correct. No space has been reserved for the object in your code. (Which, by the way, doesn't create a reference, but instead creates a pointer.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz ,I always make the mistake to call a pointer a reference and a reference a pointer... I edited the question.Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

> Since the content of the reference is null

Two mistakes there.

1. There is no reference.  You have a pointer.  Both C++ pointers and C++ references are types of handles.  So are references in C# and Java and pointers in C#.  But there's not 100% overlap between these handle types, they vary in whether they support address arithmetic (only C++ and C# pointers), and whether they can be reassigned (all except for C++ references).
2. The content of this pointer is not null.  It is uninitialized.

Your code calls `delete` on a wild pointer.  That's undefined behavior.  Calling a destructor with a wild `this` pointer is just one example of where undefined behavior can lead.

> What destructor is it calling?

C++ finds non-virtual member functions based on the type of the variable, reference, or pointer used to call them.  In your case, the destructor isn't virtual.  It's not surprising then, that the compiler converts `delete s;` into logic to test if the pointer value is null and then calls the `Sak::~Sak` destructor using that pointer value as a `this` pointer.  But the behavior is undefined, other things could happen as well, including random corruption of other memory in the process and worse (perhaps corruption of open files, affecting future runs of the program also).